# How to insert a post with multi category and with multi column deferent category in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hello all I am a new laravel, I have problem with my project. I have 2 table:

```
posts: id title category_id
category: id name(PHP, Laravel, Ruby)
```

Ex:I want result like, if I am insert a post into posts database title=Jonh and chosse two category name(PHP,Laravel), and the result will two column like  posts(id=1 title(jonh) category_id(1), id=2 title(jonh) category_id(2)) but it still not work I try to find in google and youtube follow and it not work, and here is my code:

```
View(create.blade.php)
{!!Form::open(array('route' => 'store', 'method' => 'POST'))!!}

{{Form::text('title')}}<br>

@foreach($category as $categories)
{{Form::label('category',$categories->name)}}
{{Form::checkbox('category_id', $categories->id) }}
@endforeach
<br>
{{Form::submit('submit')}}
{!!Form::close()!!}

Controller(PostsController.php)
public function create()
    {
        $category = Category::all();
        return view('create',compact('category'));
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $post = new Posts;
       $post->title = $request['title'];
       $post->category_id = $request['category_id'];
       $post->save();
    }
```

Help pls

Comment: Please give information about what is happening other than *but I cant not*.

Comment: ok I updated, sorry my poor english

Comment: I want insert a post into  multi column with categories, help me pls

Comment: Your problem is the relationship between the `Post` Molel and the `Category` Model it must be a `ManyToMany` relation not `ManyToOne` as you did !!

Comment: I am just start with laravel ,could you have some code for correct me pls

Comment: Take a look at the [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) there is a user and roles example hope that helps ;)

Comment: Is all clear or did you have some other questions ?

Comment: ok dont have now, thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the relationship between Post and Category is not correct. One post belongs to zero or more categories (you can restrict to one or more in the app layer) and one category can be associated with zero or more posts. This type of relationship is called *Many to Many*.

*Post belongsToMany Category*
*Category belongsToMany Post*

Below we have the tables structure:

----- posts -----
id INT
title VARCHAR(100)
body TEXT

----- category_post -----
category_id INT
post_id INT

----- categories -----
id INT
name VARCHAR(100)

What you should do is:

1 - create a new migration to category_post table

```php
<?php

// migrations/****_**_**_******_create_posts_table.php
Schema::create('posts', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title', 100);
    $table->text('body');
});

// migrations/****_**_**_******_create_categories_table.php
Schema::create('categories', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name', 100);
});

// migrations/****_**_**_******_create_category_post_table.php
Schema::create('category_post', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
    $table->primary(['category_id', 'post_id']);
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

2 - Change the relationship between Post and Category inside your Eloquent models.

```php
<?php

// Post.php
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}

// Category.php
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
// PostController.php
public function create()
{
    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('posts.create', compact('categories'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        // Validate the max number of characters to avoid database truncation
        'title' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100'],
        'body' => ['required', 'string'],
        // The user should select at least one category
        'categories_id' => ['required', 'array', 'min:1'],
        'categories_id.*' => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:categories,id'],
    ]);

    $post = new Post();
    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->body = $request->body;
    $post->categories()->attach($request->categories_id);

    return redirect()->route('posts.index');
}

// views/posts/create.blade.php
<select name="categories_id" multiple>
@foreach ($categories as $category)
  <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: In post.php, use this relation:
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_post', 'post_id', 'category_id');
}

Comment: Can you please give idea how to select this values in edit form ?

Answer (score 0):

That answer is correct but it only returns the last selected value, you need to change the **name attribute** to an array:

```
<select name="categories_id[]" multiple>
@foreach ($categories as $category)
  <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

then in your controller run it through a foreach loop since you're getting multiple values.

```
foreach ($request->categories as $value) {
    $post->categories()->attach($value);
}
```

The results

```
mysql> select * from category_post;
+---------+-------------+
| post_id | category_id |
+---------+-------------+
|       2 |           1 |
|       2 |           2 |
|       2 |           3 |
+---------+-------------+
```

To retrieve those values:
In controller

```
foreach ($post->categories as $category) {
    echo $category->name;
}
```

In your Blade component:

```
@forelse ($post->categories as $category)
    {{ $category->name }}
@empty
    <p>no category</p>
@endforelse
```

I hope this is helpful.
Thanks to @Lucas Silva