# Laravel - Letting users insert categories upon post creation and create new ones if they don't exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

So I'm trying to create the feature for users to add multiple categories when they create a post.

This is an example of a string getting passed to the controller:

```
$request['categories'] = "Sports, Football, Finals";
```

- The first thing I need to do is to split the string, clean it
  from blankspaces and create an array.
- Then check for every category if it exists, otherwise create new one.
  Laravel firstOrCreate() method might be well suited for this.
- Finally the ability to associate multiple categories for every post.

This is what I have so far:

**TABLES**

posts

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->integer('user_id');


        });
```

categories

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name');
        });
```

category_post

```
Schema::create('category_post', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

**Models**

Post

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category');
    }
}
```

Category

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

I don't know if I have set up the tables correctly, if I made the right model relationships and **I feel clueless on how to set up the *controller***.

I got some inspiration from these posts:

1. [How to insert a post with multi category and with multi column deferent category in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746613/how-to-insert-a-post-with-multi-category-and-with-multi-column-deferent-category)
2. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/eloquent-attach-method-for-multiple-inserts-into-a-pivot-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in [many to many Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), you must use the `belongsToMany` function in both models, so change your `Post` model like so:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}
```

Also, rename your `post` function in your `Category` model to `posts` and add `protected $fillable = ['name'];` to your `Category` model

Finally, for the controller method, you can use the following code:

```
$categoryStr = $request->input('categories');
$categories = array_map('trim', explode(',', $categoryStr));
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $catModel = App\Category::firstOrCreate(['name' => $category]);
    $catModel->posts()->save($post); //$post can be the post model that you want to associate with the category
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but I get the error `MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 452:
name
in Model.php line 452
at Model->fill(array('name' => 'test')) in Model.php line 288
at Model->__construct(array('name' => 'test')) in Model.php line 504...`

Comment: Oh, just add the following line in your `Category` model: `protected $fillable = ['name'];`

Comment: Hmm, now I get the error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()`

This is my Category model:
`<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
    }

    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
`

Post model:
`<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
 public function categories()
 {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
 }
}
`

Comment: Oh my bad, replace the last line of the controller with `$catModel->posts()->attach($post);`. I've also updated my answer. Let me know if there are any other errors

Comment: The categories gets saved, but nothing got saved to the table `category_post`, do I even need this table? 
So how is the relation between the post and it's categories saved right now?

Sorry if I ask a stupid question, I really should read up on the function attach().

Comment: What does the variable $post look like? Can you post your controller code? The code I posted should update the pivot table `category_post`

Comment: There's quite a lot going on in the post controller. I'll try to trim out some parts. Here's the $post variable: `{"title":"exampleTitle","body":"exampleBody","type":"News article","published":"1"}`

Comment: what's the output of `dd($post)`? $post needs to be either an Eloquent post model instance or a numeric id that relates to a post. Place `dd($post)` before the code where you attach the post and post the output

Comment: `Post {#201 ▼
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:4 [▼
    "title" => "test"
    "body" => "test"
    "type" => "News article"
    "published" => "1"
  ]
  #original: []
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}`

Comment: Hmm, everything does look fine and the code should update the pivot table. Try `$catModel->posts()->save($post);` or `$catModel->posts()->attach($post->id);`

Comment: Seems like it worked with `$catModel->posts()->save($post);`.
Can't tell you how much I appreciate the help on this one.
Big thanks man!